# Syncronized sorting between two ArrayLists

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, sorting

I have two ArrayLists.

- The first contains a group of words with capitalization and
  punctuation.
- The other contains this same group of words, but with the
  capitalization and punctuation removed.

.

```
ArrayList1 ..... ArrayList2

MURDER! ........ murder

It's ........... its

Hello .......... hello

Yes-Man ........ yesman

ON ............. on
```

The second array has all the words alphabetized and all the letters in each word alphabetized. It looks something like this:

```
aemnsy
demrru
ehllo
ist
no
```

I want to make it so that when I arrange the words in ArrayList two into alphabetical order, all the words from ArrayList one follow suite:

```
ArrayList1 ..... ArrayList2

Yes-Man ........ aemnsy

MURDER! ........ demrru

Hello .......... ehllo

It's ........... ist

ON ............. no
```

I tried to make a loop with a for statement or two, but it ended up not working and became very long. How do I do this? How do I do this efficiently?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a `Map` rather than two `List`s

Comment: If you can, use a `TreeMap<String, String>` where the key is the String from ArrayList2 and the value is from ArrayList1.

Comment: What's wrong with the two Collections.sort calls?

Comment: @Thihara are you sure of your comment? Have you read the question?

Comment: Oops, at first glance I thought he just needs to sort the two array lists... On second read I see why the map is the answer...

Comment: @Thihara a `Map` is a possible answer, that would depend on the real problem.

Comment: Use a map only if you are sure that the values you use as key are unique, which might not be the case in ArrayLists. If you would have double values in the keylist, you should not use a solution with a map but create a list with a pair and sort by the first value in my opinion. For the described problem however the solution with a map could be valid, except for when you have multiple anagrams for the same word in these lists. For a good answer check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17780398/sort-two-arraylists-concurrently?lq=1

Answer (score 5):

Here is a function to sort multiple lists based on a single 'key' list. The lists do not need to be the same type, here the key list is type `String` and it's used to sort a `String`, `Integer`, and `Double` list  ([**Ideone Example**](https://ideone.com/u2OICl)):

```
List<String> key = Arrays.asList("demrru", "ist", "ehllo", "aemnsy", "no");
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("MURDER!","It's", "Hello","Yes-Man", "ON");
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(2, 4, 3, 1, 5);            // Also use Integer type 
List<Double>  list3 = Arrays.asList(0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5);  // or Double type

// Sort all lists (excluding the key)
keySort(key, list1, list2, list3);

// Sort all lists (including the key)
keySort(key, key, list1, list2, list3);
```

**Output:**

```
// Sorted by key:
[Yes-Man, MURDER!, Hello, It's, ON]
[aemnsy, demrru, ehllo, ist, no]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
```

---

### Sort Function

An Ideone Example can be found [**here**](https://ideone.com/u2OICl) which includes validation of parameters and a test case.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void keySort(
                                        final List<T> key, List<?>... lists){
    // Create a List of indices
    List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < key.size(); i++)
        indices.add(i);

    // Sort the indices list based on the key
    Collections.sort(indices, new Comparator<Integer>(){
        @Override public int compare(Integer i, Integer j) {
            return key.get(i).compareTo(key.get(j));
        }
    });

    // Create a mapping that allows sorting of the List by N swaps.
    Map<Integer,Integer> swapMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(indices.size());

    // Only swaps can be used b/c we cannot create a new List of type <?>
    for(int i = 0; i < indices.size(); i++){
        int k = indices.get(i);
        while(swapMap.containsKey(k))
            k = swapMap.get(k);

        swapMap.put(i, k);
    }

    // for each list, swap elements to sort according to key list
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e : swapMap.entrySet())
        for(List<?> list : lists)
            Collections.swap(list, e.getKey(), e.getValue());
}
```

Comment: I tried that the first list is not sorted and the second one is not synced with first one!!

Answer (score 4):

**First Way - I use map whose key is from arrayList2 and value is from arrayList1. Putting data to map is up to you. After sorting arrayList2, I get its value from map.**

```
  List<String> arrList1 = new ArrayList<String>();

            arrList1.add("MURDER!");
            arrList1.add("It's");
            arrList1.add("Hello");
            arrList1.add("Yes-Man");
            arrList1.add("ON");

            List<String> arrList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
            arrList2.add("demrru");
            arrList2.add("aemnsy");
            arrList2.add("ist");
            arrList2.add("ehllo");
            arrList2.add("no"); 

            Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map1.put("aemnsy", "Yes-Man");
            map1.put("demrru", "MURDER!");
            map1.put("ehllo", "Hello");
            map1.put("ist", "It's");
            map1.put("no", "ON");

            Collections.sort(arrList2);

            for (String s : arrList2){
                System.out.println(s + "..........." + map1.get(s));
            }
```

**Second Way - Another way is you can use only TreeMap which is already sorted instead of two ArrayList.**

```
Map<String, String> map2 = new TreeMap<String, String>();
            map2.put("ehllo", "Hello");
            map2.put("aemnsy", "Yes-Man");
            map2.put("demrru", "MURDER!");
            map2.put("no", "ON");
            map2.put("ist", "It's");

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map2.entrySet())
            {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
            }
```

**Third way - only using 2 ArrayList, but we have to write sorting method by our own. Have you notice that your 2 ArrayList elements such as aemnsy from arrayList2 and Yes-Man from arrayList1 have same index? I use that point.**

```
  selectionSort1(arrList2, arrList1);

    for(int i = 0; i < arrList1.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(arrList2.get(i) + "---" + arrList1.get(i));
    }

   public static void selectionSort1(List<String> x, List<String> y) {
    for (int i=0; i<x.size()-1; i++) {
        for (int j=i+1; j<x.size(); j++) {
            if (x.get(i).compareTo(x.get(j)) > 0) {
                //... Exchange elements in first array
                String temp = x.get(i);
                x.set(i, x.get(j));
                x.set(j, temp);

                //... Exchange elements in second array
                temp = y.get(i);
                y.set(i, y.get(j));
                y.set(j, temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would very much prefer to use only a Map, but sadly that is not the objective of the exercise. However using a map for two arraylists... Well let me play around with this for a bit and I'll get back to you.

Comment: If you're going to use a `TreeMap` it would be better to declare it as `TreeMap<String,String> map2` or `NavigableMap<String, String>` in order to use all the methods in the class/interface (check my comment).

Comment: In an attempt to use the map, I discovered that the map was not retaining the original values for List1, but was instead replacing them with only one of the values of the words that were anagrams of each other. Where the other words went I do not know.

Comment: @RyanTibbetts it looks that you have never used a `Map` before. By the way, do you really need two *synchronized* `List<String>` backed up with `ArrayList<String>`? This looks like a design flaw since you can have a `AnagramWord` class with `private String anagram` and `private String word` attributes in it and a simple `List<AnagramWord>` that you can sort however you want by just providing a `Comparator<AnagramWord>`.

Comment: Your third way make my eyes bleed. With it, you're just reinventing the wheel using a `String[]` instead of `List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>` and even worse: using a selection sort instead of `Collections.sort(somethingThatImplementList)` that uses an optimized `MergeSort`.

Comment: I add third way to sort two array list. In this method. I do not use Collections.sort or Arrays.sort(). I have to write sorting by my own. In fact, writing sorting by my own is not good. But according to ur requirement of using 2 ArrayList, it may be OK!.. Hopefully!!!

Comment: If you think that would be *better*, you can opt for an OO design as I posted in a comment on your answer.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I modify my 3 way code as your comment. I remove reinventing wheel. Your suggestion for using MergeSort is good for performance. But which sorting you use is up to u.

Comment: This has been very helpful to me as I work through this complicated exercise. I thank both of you dearly for your help and input. It has been more than I expected to get.

Comment: The TreeMap sort has the caveat that the values in the list that you use as key have to be unique since it's a Map. This cannot be guaranteed when using ArrayLists since this boundary doesn't apply to them. So I wouldn't see it as a completely valid result. At least you have to know what you are sorting and that there are no double values. and if this is the case you should in my opinion use a Set and not a List.

Answer (score 0):

A Quick Answer.

```
public class MapAlph {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String txt = "Murde!r!";
        ArrayList<Character> alph = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for (int i = 0; i < txt.length(); i++)
            if (Character.isLetter(txt.charAt(i)))
                alph.add(txt.charAt(i));

        Collections.sort(alph);
        Collections.reverse(alph);
        String val = "";
        for (Character c : alph)
            val += c;

        map.put(txt, val);
        System.out.print(txt + " ........ " + map.get(txt));
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you just have that sitting around or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), if you wish.

```
Map<String, String> sortedMap = new TreeMap<String, String>();
sortedMap.put("demrru", "MURDER!");
sortedMap.put("ist", "It's");
sortedMap.put("aemnsy", "Yes-Man");
sortedMap.put("ehllo", "Hello");
sortedMap.put("no", "ON");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;


public class SortService {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> originalMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        originalMap.put("aemnsy", "Yes-Man");
        originalMap.put("demrru", "MURDER!");
        originalMap.put("ehllo", "Hello");
        originalMap.put("ist", "It's");
        originalMap.put("no", "ON");

        Map<String, String> sortedMap = new TreeMap<String, String>(originalMap);
        System.out.println(sortedMap);
    }

}
```

**output:**

```
{aemnsy=Yes-Man, demrru=MURDER!, ehllo=Hello, ist=It's, no=ON}
```