# Sort two arrayLists concurrently

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, comparator

Say I have two ArrayLists:

```
name: [Four, Three, One, Two]
num:  [4, 3, 1, 2]
```

If I do: Arrays.sort(num), then I have:

```
name: [Four, Three, One, Two]
num:  [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Is there any way I can possibly do a sort on num and have it reflected in name as well, so that I might end up with:

```
name: [One, Two, Three, Four]
num:  [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

? Please do help me out. I thought of Comparators and Objects, but barely know them at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should somehow **associate** `name` and `num` fields into one class and then have a list of instances of that specific class. In this class, provide a `compareTo()` method which checks on the numerical values. If you sort the instances, then the name fields will be in the order you desire as well.

```
class Entity implements Comparable<Entity> {
    String name;
    int num;
    Entity(String name, int num) {
        this.name = name;
        this.num = num;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Entity o) {
        if (this.num > o.num)
            return 1;
        else if (this.num < o.num)
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Test code could be like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
    entities.add(new Entity("One", 1));
    entities.add(new Entity("Two", 2));
    entities.add(new Entity("Three", 3));
    entities.add(new Entity("Four", 4));
    Collections.sort(entities);

    for (Entity entity : entities)
        System.out.print(entity.num + " => " + entity.name + " ");
}
```

Output:

> 1 => One 2 => Two 3 => Three 4 => Four

Answer (score 2):

Instead of sorting the actual arrays you can have an array with just indices

```
a[i] = i for i = 0..n
```

and you can sort this array based on your numeruc array with a custom comparator. e.g.

```
bool compare( int a, int b ) { return num[a] < num[b]; }
```

Thus you have both arrays sorted by using these indices.

Comment: I actually have this exact thing. But the problem is that it is pretty slow. To get a corresponding value of name, I have to do:

name.get(numIndex.indexOf(num.get(value)))

Comment: wont name.get(a[i]) would be sufficient if "a" is a plain array, for getting i+1 th smallest elemnt, i dont know if Array list provides a constant lookup, otherwise yes anything  involving sorting would be pretty slow.

Comment: @gran_profaci I know this is kinda an old question but I've posted an implementation of this technique for an arbitrary number of arbitrarily typed `List`s.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have repeated elements, then you could just use a sorted Map like a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) instead:

```
int[] num = {4, 3, 1, 2};
String[] name = {"Four", "Three", "One", "Two"};
TreeMap<Integer,String> sortedMap = new TreeMap<Integer,String>();
for (int i=0; i<num.length; i++) sortedMap.put(num[i], name[i]);
// Resulting sortedMap: {1=One, 2=Two, 3=Three, 4=Four}
```

If you do have repeated elements then this won't work because the keys of the map must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it doesn't make much sense to create a new class just to do multiple sorts based off a given list. I've created a function that does this, but I've posted the code in a [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24688828/1290264) so I wont repeat it. Below is an example of how to use it.

---

### Usage

Here is an example of how you can use the function to sort multiple lists of arbitrary types:

```
// The key can be any type that implements Comparable, Dupes are allowed
List<Integer> key = Arrays.asList(4, 3, 1, 2, 1);

// List Types do not need to be the same
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("Four", "Three", "One", "Two", "One");
List<Character> list2 = Arrays.asList('d', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a');

// Sorts key, list1, list2 using key as the sorting key.
keySort(key, key, list1, list2);
```

**Output:**

```
key:   [1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
list1: [One, One, Two, Three, Four]
list2: [a, a, b, c, d]
```