# Sorting a number of lists based on two lists in Java

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist, collections

I have four lists as follows:

```
    ArrayList<String> tempNameList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> tempPhoneList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> tempAddressList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> tempBirthdayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Each list contains records related to the other lists by index. I am trying to sort all the lists in ascending order by the person's Name and Birthday. I have tried using `Collections.sort()` but it only supports a single list at a time.
How do I sort all the lists by name and birthday?

Comment: Have you considered using classes?

Comment: @shmosel do you mean using the List<Object> ?

Comment: I mean `List<Person>` where `class Person` contains fields `name`, `phone`, `address` and `birthday`.

Comment: @shmosel I haven't tried that yet. My code is completed using Lists. How do I sort it using classes? I can change my code

Comment: This code shows classic “object phobia”. Create a person (or whatever name makes sense) object. Parallel arrays are not great OO.

Comment: I think I answered a similar question in the past...

Comment: @hfontanez could you please share a link ? Or else I will write a new code. Thanks

Comment: It's the same that shmosel recommended. But, in order to sort a `Person` the class needs to implement `Comparable`.

Comment: found similar question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/30821395  have a look you'll get help here

Comment: You should also convert the birthdays to actual date because in general case their sorting largely depends on the format, that is, the birthdays can be sorted only if they are presented in YYYY-MM-DD or similar format (with leading zeroes in month/day)

Answer (score 1):

Sorting of multiple lists of the same size is possible following these steps:

1. Create an array/list of indexes according to the sorting rules (first by names, then by birthdays in appropriate YYYYMMDD format, etc.)

```java
List<String> names  = Arrays.asList("bbb", "aaa", "bbb", "aaa");
List<String> phones = Arrays.asList("1023456", "1324560", "1227890", "1446752");
List<String> bdays  = Arrays.asList("20001122", "19980105", "20010614", "19990507");

int[] indexes = IntStream.range(0, names.size())
    .boxed()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(names::get).thenComparing(bdays::get))
    .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
    .toArray(); // -> [1, 3, 0, 2]
```

2. Reorder each of the input lists according to the indexes.
   A separate method may be created for this:

```java
private static List<String> sort(List<String> list, int[] indexes) {
    return Arrays.stream(indexes).mapToObj(list::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
// ...
System.out.println(sort(names,  indexes)); -> [aaa, aaa, bbb, bbb]
System.out.println(sort(phones, indexes)); -> [1324560, 1446752, 1023456, 1227890]
System.out.println(sort(bdays,  indexes)); -> [19980105, 19990507, 20001122, 20010614]
```

---

However, it would be more natural to create a container object to combine the values from the different input lists, which has become quite simple after introducing `record` classes in Java 16, and the sort these objects:

```
record Person(String name, String phone, String bday) {}

List<Person> persons = IntStream.range(0, names.size())
    .boxed()
    .map(i -> new Person(names.get(i), phones.get(i), bdays.get(i)))
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::name).thenComparing(Person::bday))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

persons.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
Person[name=aaa, phone=1324560, bday=19980105]
Person[name=aaa, phone=1446752, bday=19990507]
Person[name=bbb, phone=1023456, bday=20001122]
Person[name=bbb, phone=1227890, bday=20010614]
```